# Davinci Resolve Ubuntu 20.04 no access to microphone

Tags: permissions, microphone

actually Davinci Resolve 16 runs fine on my Ubuntu system,except fairlight cannot access the microphone. maybe it has to do with permission rights? in the permission settings for the applications, there is no button to allow microphone access for Resolve. I tested it with other audio software that has the button. When i allow other apps to use the microphone, they record. How can i fix this? Or is it any other problem?

Comment: I suppose you are running Davinci Resolve in Wine?

Comment: No, why? i installed it with the script that came with the ZIP file in Ubuntu.